# Magento 2 shipping methods showing exception UPS/USPS

Tags: magento2, shipping, ups, usps

I am trying to access magento2 shipping methods like UPS/USPS but its throwing exception "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."[image]

Comment: I am facing the same problem for FedEx service, I have tried for 5 different address with correct zip code, but still not working... Plz, provide me a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be of some address problem. See if this link given below can help you out :)

http://wiki.onestepcheckout.com/index.php?title=Shipping_methods

**EDIT :**

Just try this from a different network. The issue might be that the web services url are blocked in your office network. This prevents the request from hitting the shipping carrier servers. Also recheck your credentials before entering.

Trying from a different network connection worked for me !

Comment: Thank you @Piyush I tried it still throwing same exception.Please provide me some another solution. :) your help would be appreciated  :)

Comment: @Omkar : Are you able to solve problem by the above method?

Answer (score 3):

Hello `@Omkar` I think it may be zipcode issue. Try to enter right zipcode for billing and shipping address.

Comment: Hello @Arvind i tried it with zipcode  still giving same exception. Please give me some another solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

solution for this issue is

write a mixin or override a vendor\magento\module-ups\view\frontend\web\js\model\shipping-rates-validation-rules.js
add a region in validation rules

that is

```
getRules: function () {
            return {
                'postcode': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'country_id': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'region_id': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'region_id_input': {
                    'required': true
                }
            };
        }
```

i posted in

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12211#issuecomment-398658159